# Simple page URL rewrite with add_rewrite_rule()

Tags: rewrite-rules

I've checked on previous posts but my problem seems to not be covered by any previous answer.

I have WP installed into a subfolder

`www.example.com/sub-folder/`

and a page **password protected**

`www.example.com/sub-folder/thepage/`

What I need is the page working with

`www.example.com/thepage/`

I've added on **functions.php**

```
//Rewrite Rules
add_rewrite_rule('thepage/', 'sub-folder/thepage/', 'top');
```

and tried

```
//Rewrite Rules
add_rewrite_rule('^thepage/', 'sub-folder/thepage/', 'top');

//Rewrite Rules
add_rewrite_rule('/thepage/', '/sub-folder/thepage/', 'top');
```

But nothing has worked. This is the first time I've use this function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `add_rewrite_rule` is not a path, it the query string you want WordPress executes. This should work for `example.com/sub-folder/thepage/` (change page_id with ID of your page):

```
add_rewrite_rule('thepage/', 'index.php?page_id=12');
```

or with page slug:

```
add_rewrite_rule('thepage/', 'index.php?pagename=thepage');
```

As you have WordPress in a subdirectory and you want to rip out the directoy name, you have to [properly cofigure WordPress in sudirectory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

If you want all WordPress URLs in the format `example.com/sub-folder/` and only rip out "sub-folder" for "thepage" you have to configure the rewrite rule in the .htaccess file on the root directory, not in WordPress:

```
RewriteRule ^thepage(/)?$ sub-folder/index.php?page_id=12 [L]
```